# Is me sending some Bitcoin to a Tor service a transaction? Or only when I buy something with those Bitcoin from the Tor service?

Tags: legal, cryptocurrency, bookkeeping, record-keeping

I've started recording all my money transactions, be them fiat or Bitcoin.

Now I wonder how to record the following situation:

1. I have an existing 0.05 BTC in my Bitcoin Core wallet running on my machine.
2. I send these to the receive address displayed in the account section when logged into an .onion site.
3. Days/weeks, or immediately after it has transferred over, I buy something on the .onion site, which uses the BTC I have "loaded" into my account in step #2.

Should I record step 2 or 3? Or both? Either way seems equally correct for me, but for different reasons.

Step 2 takes it away from my direct control, but it's still "theoretically" in my control since it's my account on the .onion site, even though they could "exit scam" any day, it could get compromised, etc.

I truly can't tell which way is the correct one.

Actually, one might as well ask this question without mentioning Bitcoin at all, and just pretend as if I was talking about USD and some "clearnet" site which works in a similar manner.

Comment: Can you convert them into money back from onion site? Or its just a number on some website after your payment on step (2)?

Comment: note: the primary reason to buy something with Bitcoin *on Tor* is that you're buying something illegal. Even crypto enthusiasts use Bitcoin without Tor.

Comment: Questions about taxes or laws should have a country tag.